# dojo.fx.wipeIn problem with object with style="display: none;"

Tags: animation, dojo

I want to wipe in with object that define style with `display: none;`:

```
dojo.fx.wipeIn({
node: dojo.byId("target"),
duration: 500
}).play();
```

but the animation could not play.
what is problem?

i use this for showing the display properties but still showing nothing. The alert message is empty.

```
    dojo.fx.wipeIn({
        node: dojo.byId("target"),
        duration: 500,
        beforeBegin: function(){
            alert(dojo.byId("target").style.display);
        },
        onEnd: function() {
            alert(dojo.byId("target").style.display);
        }
    }).play();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me with a very simple page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>wipeIn test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.fx");

        dojo.addOnLoad(function() { 
                dojo.fx.wipeIn({node: 'target', duration: 500}).play();
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="target" style="display:none; background-color: #444; color: #fff; height: 400px; width:300px;">
            <br />Unnecessary animation :-)
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you post more of the code you're using?

Answer (score 0):

check this :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>wipeIn test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3.2/dojo/dojo.xd.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dojo.fx");

        dojo.addOnLoad(function() { 
                dojo.fx.wipeIn({node: 'target', duration: 500}).play();
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #target {
            display:none; background-color: #444; color: #fff; height: 400px; width:300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="target">
            <br />Unnecessary animation :-)
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when use `display: none;` in stylesheet the dojo faild.

Comment: This looks to be a bug in dojo.fx.wipeIn as moving the style declaration inline fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but it seems that when `display: none;` is placed in-line with the html it works. That's why the simple examples work on the Dojo/fx documentation page.

```
<div id="target" style="display:none; background-color: #444; color: #fff; height: 400px; width:300px;">
   <br />Unnecessary animation :-)
 </div>
```

Comment: its about Dojo to fix, not the CSS that could be placed inline.